# Unwanted 'Favourites' folder in Photos App

Tags: ipad, photos

When viewing a photo I clicked on the heart icon in the iPad photo app by mistake and a Favourites folder was created.
Although the photo was deleted from the Favourites folder, the empty folder remains. Has anyone any idea how to remove the empty Favourites folder.
Very annoying to have it there with nothing inside it and no obvious way to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own query - I found out that the empty 'favourites' folder disappears about a week after all its contents have been deleted. Problem solved with no intervention.